# where condition in fill_between isn't working

Tags: python, matplotlib

Trying to use the following code:

```
ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = closep > closep[0], facecolor = 'g', alpha = 0.3) 
ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = closep < closep[0], facecolor = 'r', alpha = 0.3)
```

It isn't working at all

I did the following things:
1. Tried running just the '>' condition: it filled the entire figure
2. Tried running just the '<' condition: it didn't fill anything

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 31)
df = web.DataReader('TWTR', 'yahoo', start, end)
df.reset_index(inplace = True)

stock = 'Twitter'

date = df['Date'].tolist()

closep = df['Close'].tolist()

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
ax1.plot_date(date, closep, '-', label = 'Price')
ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = closep > closep[0], facecolor = 'g', alpha = 0.3) 
ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = closep < closep[0], facecolor = 'r', alpha = 0.3)

for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
 label.set_rotation(45)

ax1.grid(True)
ax1.xaxis.label.set_color('c')
ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('r')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('Close Price')
plt.title(stock)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

On running the above I get:

[image: result1: All Fill]

I tried the following:

```
#ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = closep > closep[0], facecolor = 'g', alpha = 0.3) 
ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = closep < closep[0], facecolor = 'r', alpha = 0.3)
```

This gives me:

[image: result2: No Fill]

Next I tried this:

```
ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = closep > closep[0], facecolor = 'g', alpha = 0.3) 
#ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = closep < closep[0], facecolor = 'r', alpha = 0.3)
```

Which gave me:
[image: result3: All Fill]

Ideally, the are above closep[0] should have been coloured and the one below it should have been blank.

However, everything is getting filled. Moreover, just running the '>' fills everything and just running the '<' condition doesn't fill anything

I use python2.7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
import datetime as dt
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas_datareader.data as web

start = dt.datetime(2000, 1, 1)
end = dt.datetime(2016, 12, 31)
df = web.DataReader('TWTR', 'yahoo', start, end)
df.reset_index(inplace = True)

stock = 'Twitter'

date = df['Date'].tolist()

closep = df['Close'].tolist()

fig = plt.figure()

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((1,1), (0,0))
ax1.plot_date(date, closep, '-', label = 'Price')
ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = [i > closep[0] for i in closep], facecolor = 'g', alpha = 0.3) 
ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = [i < closep[0] for i in closep] , facecolor = 'r', alpha = 0.3)

for label in ax1.xaxis.get_ticklabels():
 label.set_rotation(45)

ax1.grid(True)
ax1.xaxis.label.set_color('c')
ax1.yaxis.label.set_color('r')
plt.xlabel('date')
plt.ylabel('Close Price')
plt.title(stock)
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: It worked! Thanks! Can you please explain why the for loop was necessary? Haven't come across it anywhere. Also, why was there a different output when the '>/<' conditions were used separately?

Comment: @ketaningle80 well, you can't compare a list to a value in python.  Now, if you didn't do the .tolist() at the end of df['close'] you, it would have worked because you can compare a np.array to a value. `closep = df['Close']` then `ax1.fill_between(date, closep, closep[0], where = closep < closep[0], facecolor = 'r', alpha = 0.3)` will work.